# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.Sun in google app engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, gradle

I have integrated spring mvc with google oauth The app runs fine on local application server. When deployed on google cloud app engine I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.Sun not found error.

Is rt.jar not included in google app engine ? Although I copied rt.jar in my project lib folder, the project deployment fails with following error

\WEB-INF\lib\rt.jar is too large. Consider using --enable_jar_splitting.

How do i enable jar splitting if this is the right approach in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for in the following thread

["ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.Sun" when running Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853312/classnotfoundexception-sun-security-provider-sun-when-running-google-cloud-da)

The problem is that sun.security.provider.Sun doesn't appear on the App Engine JRE whitelist, so the classloader can't instantiate instances of it:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

the class is not whitelisted in GAE jre.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.