# "ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.Sun" when running Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

A `DoFn` in our Dataflow pipeline contains a type with a `Random` field pointing to a `SecureRandom` instance, and that field fails to deserialize when running in the Dataflow service using `DataflowPipelineRunner`. (stack trace below)

We create the `SecureRandom` using its default ctor, which happens to hand back an instance that uses `sun.security.provider.Sun` as its `java.security.Provider` (see [`SecureRandom#getProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getProvider())). `SecureRandom` extends `Random`, which is serializable.

The Dataflow service chokes when trying to deserialize this class because it can't create `sun.security.provider.Sun`.

Looking closer at the stack trace, I see that deserialization happens through `com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.UserClassLoader`, and now my theory is that this classloader doesn't allow loading of `sun.*` classes, or at least this particular `sun.*` class.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to deserialize com.example.Example@13e88d
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.deserializeFromByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.clone(SerializableUtils.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$Bound.<init>(ParDo.java:683)
    [...]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.Sun
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.UserClassLoader.loadClass(UserClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `sun.security.provider.Sun` doesn't appear on the App Engine JRE whitelist, so the classloader can't instantiate instances of it:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

But luckily you can still say `new SecureRandom()` in the same environment.

To work around the problem, we added a custom de/serialization hook to the class with the `Random` field. Simplified example:

```
class Example implements Serializable {

  // See comments on {@link #writeObject} for why this is transient.
  // Should be treated as final, but can't be declared as such.
  private transient Random random;

  //
  // [Guts of the class go here...]
  //

  /**
   * Serialization hook to handle the transient Random field.
   */
  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    if (random instanceof SecureRandom) {
      // Write a null to tell readObject() to create a new
      // SecureRandom during deserialization; null is safe to use
      // as a placeholder because the constructor disallows null
      // Randoms.
      //
      // The dataflow cloud environment won't deserialize
      // SecureRandom instances that use sun.security.provider.Sun
      // as their Provider, because it's a system
      // class that's not on the App Engine whitelist:
      // https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist
      out.writeObject(null);
    } else {
      out.writeObject(random);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Deserialization hook to initialize the transient Random field.
   */
  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    Object newRandom = in.readObject();
    if (newRandom == null) {
      // writeObject() will write a null if the original field was
      // SecureRandom; create a new instance to replace it. See
      // comments in writeObject() for background.
      random = new SecureRandom();
      random.nextDouble(); // force seeding
    } else {
      random = (Random) newRandom;
    }
  }
}
```